# Jenkins master and slave node configuration

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and I have configured master-slave nodes as shown below, but I need help to configure the no of executors in each of the below slave nodes

[image]

Currently, I have configured 100 executors in each slave nodes

How many no of executors I can configure in each slave node and what fact(memory, RAM, etc) need to take consider when increasing the no of executors?

Maximum how many no of executors I can configure in each server?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well it totally depends on your usage. There are multiple factors such as how much cpu and memory is available, how the build are going to execute and what kind of builds, how frequent these build should run etc. But I can clearly say that 100 is too big number. I would suggest go with 20 builds (if builds run frequently and have fair amount of CPU and memory) first and observe if is there any issue with numbers or not then you can increase accordingly.

here is very nice article check this out [https://www.avantica.com/blog/jenkins-balance-load-master-slave-setup#:~:text=Jobs%20are%20built%20using%20executors,to%20build%20two%20different%20tasks](https://www.avantica.com/blog/jenkins-balance-load-master-slave-setup#:%7E:text=Jobs%20are%20built%20using%20executors,to%20build%20two%20different%20tasks).